# Laravel - Browser doesn't show logos and effects?

Tags: php, laravel

There was no error in running my Laravel project, but my project has not been visible in the browser with Laravel logos and effects.

What can I do to show Laravel effects in browser?

It stills shown xampp logo and there has no displayed texts and code here in my browser

How can I fix this error?

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using the asset helper example: asset('image.jpg') to get the image source?

Comment: Are you already familiar with the MVC architecture of Laravel?

Comment: You can run `php artisan serve` in the terminal in order to serve laravel on webserver.